# Method / Software for Creating Images based on Dynamically Updatable Templates?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, interface-design, css, automation

So, for example, I want to create 2 ADS but the text and the photo featured will be different between the two.
How can I create the same design using something like a template that can also be updated and implement the changes across them?

---

### Example

#### My Data

- copy-1: Geometry
- copy-2: Craft
- image-1: geometry.jpg
- image-2: craft.jpg

#### Desired Result

[image: geometry]
[image: craft]

---

I don't know if there is a UX/UI tool that can do that or if a more 'programmatic' approach can be implemented (like CSS).

---

#### images credits:

- https://www.pexels.com/photo/geometric-decoration-5836/ by Kaboompics .com
- https://www.pexels.com/photo/art-materials-arts-close-up-color-369449/ by George Becker

Comment: Yes. Illustrator has [data merge functionality](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/data-driven-graphics-templates-variables.html).

Answer (score 1):

Both Illustrator and InDesign use [Data Merge](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/data-driven-graphics-templates-variables.html), which takes a list in CSV format including pairs of text/image in a line-by-line comma-separated format, and generates composite files. Your source file will look like this (assumes Windows machine):

> @photo,text
>
> C:\Photos\geometry.jpg,Geometry
>
> C:\Photos\craft.jpg,Craft

An AI or INDD template will then need to be set up to pull this info from the CSV and into an actual design, which can replicate your template exactly.

Comment: Photoshop can also do datamerge. https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-data-driven-graphics.html

Answer (score 0):

A large amount of software are capable of doing this. Illustrator, and InDesign can do this, photoshop can do this with a little bit of work. However, the canonical way to do this has been imagemagic. Not only can it do this fast, it can do it fully automated and is not encumbered with a license that stops you form doing this on a server.

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted, I think imagemagick is a great tool for tasks like these.

Comment: @mdomino some people really dislike the idea behind imagemagic. Otoh, it could just as easily be a misclick.